# How to override super-class constructor with array parameter in OOP PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, overriding

Hello i have a problem in OOP PHP.
I try override constructor from superclass to subclass with array parameter in it.
This is my superclass code :

```
    <?php
        class Person 
        {
        
            private $firstName;
            private $lastName;
            private $gender;
            private $dob;
            private $address;
            private $country;
            private $phone;
            private $occupation;
            
            public function __construct($array) {
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
            

                public function setFirstName($firstName) {
                    $this->firstName = $firstName;
                }

                public function getFirstName() {
                    return $this->firstName;
                }
            // Another Getter and Setter
            // ...
```

And this is my subclass code :

```
<?php

    class Register extends Person
    {
    
        private $nickName;
        private $email;
        
        public function __construct($array) {
            parent::__construct($array);
        }
        
        // Getter and Setter
        // ...
```

But when i try to access nickName and email, i get an error  like this :

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Register::$email in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\oop\class\person.class.php on line 16
```

And this is my test code :

```
<?php
    function __autoload($myClass) {
        require_once 'class/' . $myClass . '.class.php';
    }
    
    $data = array(
        'firstname'     => $_POST['first_name'],
        'lastname'      => $_POST['last_name'],
        'nickname'      => $_POST['nick_name'],
        'gender'        => $_POST['gender'],
        'dob'           => $_POST['dob'],
        'address'       => $_POST['address'],
        'zipcode'       => $_POST['zipcode'],
        'country'       => $_POST['country'],
        'phone_number'  => $_POST['phone_number'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'occupation'    => $_POST['occupation']
    );
    
    
    $account = new Register($data);
    echo $account->getFirstName();
    
    // Proses DB
    // $db->insert($account);
    
?>
```

Any Sugesstion?
Thank you.

## Answer :

I already find solutions. Key name in array must same with class property.
In array i write `firstname` and property `firstName`, the correct way is `firstName` in both, array and property.

Comment: you have make the class members protected instead of private so that it can be accessed in your child class.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make your private properties `protected`, so they can be accessed from a parent method.

Another option is to initialize the subclass's properties in the subclass constructor, and remove those entries from the array:

```
class Register extends Person
{

    private $nickName;
    private $email;

    public function __construct($array) {
        if (isset($array(['nickName'])) {
            $this->nickName = $array['nickName'];
            unset $array(['nickName'];
        }
        if (isset($array(['email'])) {
            $this->email = $array['email'];
            unset $array(['email'];
        }
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is [how visibility works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in PHP. If you want to access a property in a sub-class then it has to be either `public` or `protected`.

`private` properties are *only* visible inside the class that defined it.

Comment: Okay, i already change `private` to `protected`. But i'm echo value it not show. In code above.

Comment: @fanjavaid Please add the code of the `getFirstName()` method to your question, so that we can see what it does.